# Creating server side methods for a Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I just went through the tutorial on writing a Java servlet using the example at:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html

What isn't clear to me is how developers implement methods inside this servlet that can be called by a client. The doGet method is where the http request lands. One way is to pass in a querystring, post body or header that contains information indicating a method to execute and then just create a class with methods to carry out based upon which method was indicated.

Or is there a more "built-in" way that a Java servlet can wrap methods and method parameters in the client call?

Answer (score 0):

`implement methods inside this servlet that can be called by a client`: the client does not call the servlet method at all. It is the server that `routes` a HTTP request to a certain piece of code, the servlet's GET, POST, etc  method.

The servlet container is hit with an `GET` method on a URL like `/my/servlet/info`. The URL ist translated into a servlet (by the servlet's path) and then the servlet's get method is called. Based on the URl the servlet container decides what servlet to use.

Comment: Yes, I see that but in a servlet, only the doGet is executed, so if I call http://www.mydomain.com/MyServlet, I need a way to indicate what piece of code within MyServlet to execute. I tried just adding a querystring parameter like ?method=somemethod&p=1. This works but I'm just not sure if there is a built-in way of doing all this wrapping and unwrapping of method names and parameters.

Comment: `only the doGet is executed`, no, the servlet API has all HTTP methods doGet, doPost, doPut, doDelete,... tor esponse to the corresponding [HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Comment: `This works but I'm just not sure if there is a built-in way of doing all this wrapping and unwrapping`, servlets are doing all this. Maybe have a look to a REST api like [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Using_Path).

Answer (score 0):

In general, a servlet is just an endpoint, usually an HTTP endpoint. It looks to me that you don't want to serve raw HTTP; have a look into JAX-RS ([tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)).